# Set variable equal to a number in a text file Batch

Tags: variables, batch-file, text-files

I have a batch file (`tickets.bat`) and each time you create a different ticket, by setting multiple variables and echoing the variables to a text file, I want the ticket number to go up by 1. I tried to do this by creating a `number.txt` file and each time you go through the loop and create a new ticket, it sets `%pnumber%` to the text file, and then sets `%number%` to `%pnumber%` plus 1. But `%pnumber%` keeps setting to 0, even when the `number.txt` file contains the number 1 and doesn't change. This is what I have:

```
:start
cls
echo Enter Ticket Info Here:
set /p name="Name:"
echo Press Enter to Show Ticket Preview
set /a pnumber=C:\Batch\ticket\number.txt
set /a number=%pnumber%+1
echo %number% > "C:\Batch\ticket\number.txt"
echo %name% Ticket Number %number%
pause
goto start
```

It looks like my problem is that `%pnumber%` always sets to 0. Unless I'm missing something else. Basically, I need it to always increase `%number%` by 1, even if you close the Batch job and open it up again, so that's why I went to using a `.txt` file. Is it not seeing the number in the text file or something? It's one number on one line. Thank you.

Comment: Your file is not read so pnumber is never set.  See set /p used in answer(s)  If you add echoes to check variables (echo var=%var%) you can quickly see problems like this. Also, you need a pause after the "Press enter ..." message.

Comment: @sjoy Why was pnumber never set? And why use /p versus /a? When I did it the way you said it worked fine, just wondering why it did. Also, thanks for the tip to add echoes to check variables, I will definitely use that in the future.

Comment: Two reasons pnumber not set: No redirection < for file, but even if there had been it would have failed because set /a would read the redirection symbol as a mathematical operator. Set /a (arithmetic) as @sashaDee explains. Read [here](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) about SET, then search the site for "redirection." Then browse the CMD commands. Bookmark SS64 and use it first when you run into problems; it's great. (BTW, no need for same questions in multiple comments.)

Comment: Thank you. Will check it out. Apologize for the same comment. @sjoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like this :

```
@echo Off
:start
cls
echo Enter Ticket Info Here:
set /p name="Name:"
echo Press Enter to Show Ticket Preview
set /p pnumber=<C:\Batch\ticket\number.txt
set /a number=%pnumber%+1
echo %number% >C:\Batch\ticket\number.txt
echo %name% Ticket Number %number%
pause
goto start
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just wondering, though, why did set /p work, rather than set /a and also why did it work, when setting pnumber, to do =< ? Thank you again, worked perfectly, just wondering why.

Comment: `Set /a`is to make some arithmetic calculation `set /a Result=3+4` To get a value from a file you can use set /p with the redirection char `<` to the file.

Comment: Thank you. Makes more sense now. @SachaDee